# Finding the antiderivative of $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}$$. 
Let $g(x)$ be an antiderivative of $f(x)$. If $g(5)=7$, then what is the value of $g(1)$? 
I tried doing integrating by parts repeatedly, but no success. Wolfram Alpha also gives something in a different type of function which I don't know. 
Please help?

Comment: It is unlikely this was your teacher's intent. Could it be that the root is a square and not a cubic? as stated this integral has no closed form involving non special functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g(x)=\int\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}\ dx\quad\mbox{and}\quad g(5)=7$$
So now
$$\int_1^5\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}\ dx=g(5)-g(1)=7-g(1)$$
Which implies that
$$g(1)=7-\int_1^5\sqrt[3]{x^2+2x}\ dx$$
Note that this integral does not have a solution in terms of elementary mathematical functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are confident with a numerical solution , here is it :

Because of

$$g(5)-g(1)=\int_1^5 (x^2+2x)^\frac{1}{3}dx=9.729162187801335050406060297$$

we get

$$g(1)=g(5)-9.729162187801335050406060297=-2.729162187801335050406060298$$

Comment: Very strange feature ...

Comment: And also strange is the rounding-error by PARI in the last digit ...

Comment: How did you calculate the definite integral?

Comment: Numerically, with PARI/GP, a calculator-software.

Comment: And is there a method to calculate it?

Comment: @Peter The last comment suggests that your answer, correct as it is, misses some pedagogical point...

Answer (score -1):

Which is the exact phrasing of the question? I mean, maybe you are not asked to *compute* but just to *express* the value in terms of $g$, i.e.:
$$g(1)=\int_5^1 \sqrt[3]{x^2+2 x} \, dx +7$$
because, at the end of the day, the definition of $g$ is simply:
$$g(x)=\int_5^x \sqrt[3]{t^2+2 t} \, dt +7$$